# Can't get jQuery autocomplete to work

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I've been trying at it for a while, but I can't seem to get jQuery autocomplete to work. I have a search box that I want enable autocomplete on, called `#searchBox`. I have the following jQuery code:

```
  $(function(){
    $("input, textarea, select, button").uniform();
    $('#searchPost').submit(function(event) {
    if ($(this).find('#searchBox').val() == '') {
         event.preventDefault();
    }
    });
    $("#searchBox").autocomplete({
            source: "php/searchAC.php"
    });
  });
```

The first part skins my forms, the second part disallows search form submit if there's an empty field, and the last part is the autocomplete. Here is php/searchAC.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","foo","bar");
mysql_select_db("coupons", $con);

$currentZone = $_SESSION["zoneSelected"];
$results = mysql_query("SELECT id,retailerName,savingsDetails,dateExp FROM coupons WHERE retailerName LIKE '%" . $_GET['term'] . "%' OR description LIKE '%" . $_GET['term'] . "%' AND dateExp > CURDATE() AND zone='$currentZone' AND approved <> 0"); 
$printResults = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results))
{
    $printResults[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($printResults);
?>
```

I have all the proper jQuery UI stylesheets and files included in the head of my files. When I run this, it doesn't show any behavior indicating that there is autocomplete enabled. I'm pretty new to jQuery so I may have missed a few simple things. Any help?

Comment: Can you post a demo that reproduces your problem (on [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), perhaps)? Also, `$(this).find('#searchBox').val()` could be replaced with `$('#searchBox').val()` it's not a *big* saving, though.

Comment: I don't know if I'd be able to put it on JS Fiddle since I want to be accessing a database on my server.

Comment: That's a fair point, you could use a pre-populated array of values hardcoded in the script though, rather than a dynamically-loaded list. At least that way it'd either show the dynamic loading as the problem, or clear it from the potential-problems list...

Comment: can you post the echo(ed) `json_encode($printResults);` secondly can you see the `json_encode($printResults)` in fire bug??

Comment: Can you see hits on your php page when you expect it to be trying to do auto-complete stuff? If not then it doesn't really matter if the page it needs is non-existant. ;-)

Comment: If you test with a `source: ["first","second","third"]` does that work?

Comment: @Mark, no, it doesn't not work with that. This means I should begin looking at my code for problems before I try getting a dynamic array.

Comment: I would comment out the first two parts and test it alone then (as a start...) but you do your work YOUR way :)

Comment: Hmm. I even tried copying the direct example here: http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/ and it still didn't work properly.

Comment: here is a fiddle page to get ya started: http://jsfiddle.net/HmTLY/

Comment: Can you post the portion of your code where you put links to jquery and jquery UI?

Comment: I have it working on a local array now (one of my other jQuery scripts was interfering). Now the entire problem lies in reading from the remote database.

Answer (score 0):

I think your syntax for the autocompelte looks wrong...

Try:

```
$("#searchBox").autocomplete("php/searchAC.php");
```

From http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete/autocomplete#url_or_dataoptions

Not sure where you got your syntax from.

This fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/2qcUT/) gives a 404 error when you type in the box because it is trying to hit that url in the autocomplete. I wasn't getting this with your syntax.

Comment: I make the assumption here: http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#default whereas yours is the predecessor plugin

Comment: dang! That'll just teach me to go for the top hit in google rather than looking a few down for the more uptodate version. Oh well, I'll get my coat then. :) At least it answers the question of where that syntax came from. ;-)

Comment: In your defense he DID change the syntax when he ported it from the plugin to the UI code base: http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-autocomplete/ AND here is the migration guide for those in need: http://www.learningjquery.com/2010/06/autocomplete-migration-guide